# DocuSign embedded signing URL length limit for IE11?

Tags: docusignapi

As mentioned in the October release notes,

> DocuSign will be making a change to the URL returned by the following
>   API endpoint:
>
> https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient
>
> The URL returned by this endpoint will be significantly longer. This
>   is currently limited by IE11 which has a URL length limit of 2083
>   characters but DocuSign reserves the right to increase the URL length
>   beyond this limitation in the future.

We are using above API in our application for embedded signing, where application is redirecting a recipient to the URL which are returned by this API.

**Now main question is that what happen if user is using IE 11 and URL returned by this API is exceeded IE 11 URL limit, Will this change work for IE 11 user as it is? If no then how IE 11 user can use embedded signing functionality?**

```
// JavaScript code to redirect user
window.location.href = recipientViewUrl; (URL return by above API)
```

Comment: are you saying the URL returned by the API is more than 2083 characters? I am thinking that maybe you mean the URL that your app is using that embed this URL as part of it

Comment: Yes URL which returned in above API response & app just redirecting user to same URL. So what if this URL is longer than 2083 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If DocuSign returns a URL that is longer than 2083 characters then the URL redirection won't work in IE 11. [Since DocuSign supports IE 11](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-system-requirements), returned URLs will not be longer than 2083 characters.

At some point in the future, DocuSign could drop support for IE 11 and the returned URLs might then become longer.

Therefore, you should build your application with no assumptions about the length of the URL that will be returned from the API call.